# Align the picture height

Tags: css

I have image

```
 <div class="thumb-container">
                <a href="@Url.Action("OriginalPicture", new { id = Model.Id })" target="_blank">
                    <img  class="imageResource" alt="picture" src="@Url.Action("Picture", new { id = Model.Id })" />
                </a>
            </div>
```

In my css I have added class:

```
  .thumb-container {height: 155px;}
```

I expect that, if I have an image with height 155px it fills all height and if I have small image it fills some part of this div - element. But I see, that small picture is stretched

Comment: What is `imageResource`?

Comment: In general, it is a recommended practice to serve server side resized pictures. Firstly to avoid browser dirty resize (compared to a real resize), secondly to avoid large pictures to be downloaded where only a reduced version is required and thirdly because it's easier to choose how to deal with aspect ratio (keep ratio, stretch, pan, ...)

Comment: it is fake class. It helps me in jquery logic

Comment: Please show us any CSS that you're applying to `imageResource`.

Comment: there is no css for this class

Comment: What is your question? If you only set a height to an image, the width will get computed in way that the dimension ratio keeps the same.

Comment: I have upload image 24x24 now I see 240x240 I don't understand what happends with it

Comment: You may have uploaded the image at 24x24px, but the image you're seeing might be resized on the server side. What are the width and height of the image that is actually outputted? I would bet 240x240!